# I'm trying do flip an image vertically in ASM

Tags: image-processing, assembly, arm

I'm trying to flip an image vertically using the following code:

```
flipV:

ldr r0, =pic2 
ldr r7, =#0x06800000 ;vram

ldr r1, =#0x18000 ;point do last byte
ldr r6, =#0x18000 ;counter
mov r5,#0

loop:

ldr r4,[r0,r5]
str r4,[r7,r1]

add r5,r5,#1
sub r1, r1,#1

subs r6, r6,#1
bne loop
bx    lr
```

He takes the last byte and swap with first, last - 1 swap with first + 1, and so on.

I'm getting the flip image, but it is distorted. ex

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR2lX.png << original
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXih.png << flipped

Could anyone help me fix this? I have no idea why this is happening. I began to learn about image processing awhile ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your code loads and stores 4 bytes at a time. Assuming one pixel is indeed 4 bytes, try:

```
flipV:

ldr r0, =pic2
ldr r7, =#0x06800000 ;vram

ldr r1, =#0x17ffc ;point to last pixel
ldr r6, =#0x18000 ;counter
mov r5, #0

loop:

ldr r4, [r0, r5]
str r4, [r7, r1]

add r5, r5, #4
sub r1, r1, #4

subs r6, r6, #4
bne loop
bx lr
```

Also, this is not a vertical flip but a 180 degrees rotation of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the appearance of the output file, I'm going to assume that your image is stored 1 byte per pixel, with RGB planes stored separately.

You are loading and storing 4 bytes at a time, and while you are reversing the order of the 32-bit words in the image, you aren't reversing the order of the bytes within the words, which causes the distortion, which is occurring in 4-pixel wide bands.

It means that pixels start off in this order:

```
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
```

but end up in this order:

```
MNOP IJKL EFGH ABCD
```

but you want them in this order:

```
PONM LKJI HGFE DCBA
```

Try using the `rev` opcode to reverse the byte order before storing:

```
ldr r4, [r0, r5]
rev r4, r4
str r4, [r7, r1]
```

You also need to increment/decrement by 4 each time as per scottt's answer.